# Passing row values to functions in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Can you pass a value from an inserted row into a Postgres function?

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
create or replace function get_value(value integer) returns int AS $$
    begin
        --do stuff here that mutates value using postgres features, like sequences
        return value;
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create table foo (
    value int default get_value(value_from_inserted_row)
);

insert into foo (value) values (5);
```

The idea is that `value_from_inserted_row` would be `5`, which would then be transformed by the function `get_value`. I would like to be able to apply it across multiple tables, if possible.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a trigger, or (in PostgreSQL), a rule.

Comment: thank you for the info! im gonna edit my question and clarify that it would be nice if i could apply it across multiple tables.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what "stuff" you want to do. Overall, if you wish to mutate a value inserted into a table, a `BEFORE` trigger is exactly what you need. You can write triggers that can be applied to multiple different tables using a variety of techniques, but you'll have to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: You are looking for something like this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61271/how-to-access-new-or-old-field-given-only-the-fields-name